# append to list the result of a thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

this is my code:

```
import threading

def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    print '{Worker: %s}' % num
    return

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
print(threads)
```

and this is the result from above code:

```
{Worker: 0}
{Worker: 1}
{Worker: 2}
{Worker: 3}
{Worker: 4}
[<Thread(Thread-1, stopped 17204)>, <Thread(Thread-2, stopped 852)>, <Thread(Thread-3, stopped 17092)>, <Thread(Thread-4, stopped 10632)>, <Thread(Thread-5, stopped 2396)>]
```

how can i append those results to list and create a list something like this:

```
[[{Worker: 0}],[{Worker: 1}],[{Worker: 2}],[{Worker: 3}],[{Worker: 4}]]
```

---

**edited:** in reality my def contain a request REST method and it consume some seconds and after some trying i found thread not wait to get result and not fill array list, then i reform my code into a string variable to simulate for you, in this situation i put a time.sleep(1) in first line of def and then run thread, it's have a empty list.... i less sleep time to 0.001 till get result and thread work and array have populated.

```
import threading

def worker(txt):
    """thread worker function"""
    if txt != '[{}]':
        time.sleep(0.01) # this time has empty result till replace with 0.001 or lesser
        lst.append(['{Worker: %s}' % txt])
        # time.sleep(5)
        return


xx = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr','stw','xyz']

threads, lst = [], []
for i in xx:
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    # t.join()
print(lst) #[['{Worker: abc}'], ['{Worker: jkl}'], ['{Worker: ghi}'], ['{Worker: def}']] for 0.001 sleep time
# print(threads)
```

Comment: So you want to store dictionaries or strings that look like dictionaries ?

Comment: It does not matter, my problem is that when def run from thread i can't append it to list, but when run def from simple for loop i can do that.

Comment: What's getting returned in worker(num)?

Comment: i edit my question and explain it again and more transparent, please check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import threading

def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    lst.append(['{Worker: %s}' % num])
    return

threads, lst = [], []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
print(lst)
#print(threads)

# [['{Worker: 0}'], ['{Worker: 1}'], ['{Worker: 2}'], ['{Worker: 3}'], ['{Worker: 4}']]
```

Comment: yes this is! tnx. but how about complex def? i have a def that contain a REST request, until that request is responsed the thread is closed and array list is gone empty.

Comment: i simulate it for a simple time.sleep(0.001) instead REST, the thread will work but when i increase time, the thread not work and list have been empty.

Comment: Your asked question is already answered. If you have any further questions, feel free to post as a new SO question and that might receive a lot more attention to your problem. Thanks.

Comment: i edit my question and explain it again and more transparent. if is necessary i ask a new question about it?

Comment: I suggest ask a new question. Editing this question won't get much attention as the other does. But make sure you explain the contexts, a sample input or output (if there). :)

Comment: thanks for your advise, but if it is possible please you answer it here, because you answer it once. @theausome

Comment: Answer is missing a join() for all the threads, which is why the list is empty when the threads take longer to run. The program was not waiting for them to complete before printing the list.